# Using Comparator with List of Objects in Java

Tags: java, generics, java-8, comparator

I'd like to sort my objects of Type AVLNode by their key (type String). I instantiated a Comparator and want to apply the `compareTo` Method on the String attribute. But, my IDE shows me the error `Cannot resolve method compareTo`. I don't understand why I cant use the `compareTo` method on a string an this point.

```
import java.util.*;

public class AVLTreeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Comparator<AVLNode>myComp2 = new Comparator<AVLNode>() {
            @Override public int compare(AVLNode n1, AVLNode n2) {
                return n1.getKey().compareTo(n2.getKey());
            }
        };

        AVLNode<String, AVLNode> a1 = new AVLNode( "test3", new Cuboid (2,3,4,5,6,7) );
        AVLNode<String, AVLNode> a2 = new AVLNode( "test2", new Cuboid (2,3,4,5,6,7) );
        AVLNode<String, AVLNode> a3 = new AVLNode( "test8", new Cuboid (2,3,4,5,6,7) );
        AVLNode<String, AVLNode> a4 = new AVLNode( "test1", new Cuboid (2,3,4,5,6,7) );

        List<AVLNode> listOfNodes = new ArrayList<AVLNode>();
        listOfNodes.add(a1);
        listOfNodes.add(a2);
        listOfNodes.add(a3);
        listOfNodes.add(a4);
        Collections.sort(listOfNodes, myComp2);

        for (AVLNode node : listOfNodes){
            System.out.println(node);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my AVLNode Class

```
public class AVLNode<K, V>  {

    private AVLNode<K, V> left, right, parent;
    private int height = 1;
    private K key;
    private V value;

    public AVLNode() {}
    public AVLNode(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }


    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `K` doesn't conform to `Comparable` in `AVLNode`

Comment: Java 8. Edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above compiler doesn't know that `n1.getKey()` returns `String`, so it assumes that `Object` will be returned. Anyway for `Collections.sort()` to work your code can be modified this way, see below. You haven't provided implementation of your `Cuboid`, so I replaced it with string.

```
public class AVLTreeTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Comparator myComp2 = new Comparator<AVLNode>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(AVLNode n1, AVLNode n2) {
        return ((String)n1.getKey()).compareTo((String)n2.getKey());
      }
    };

    AVLNode<String, AVLNode> a1 = new AVLNode("test3", "asd");
    AVLNode<String, AVLNode> a2 = new AVLNode("test2", "bds");
    AVLNode<String, AVLNode> a3 = new AVLNode("test8", "asdfas");
    AVLNode<String, AVLNode> a4 = new AVLNode("test1", "asdfasdf");

    List<AVLNode> listOfNodes = new ArrayList<AVLNode>();
    listOfNodes.add(a1);
    listOfNodes.add(a2);
    listOfNodes.add(a3);
    listOfNodes.add(a4);
    Collections.sort(listOfNodes, myComp2);

    for (AVLNode node : listOfNodes) {
      System.out.println(node);
    }
  }
}

class AVLNode<K, V> {

  private AVLNode<K, V> left, right, parent;
  private int height = 1;
  private K key;
  private V value;

  public AVLNode() {
  }

  public AVLNode(K key, V value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }


  public V getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public K getKey() {
    return key;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "AVLNode{" +
        "left=" + left +
        ", right=" + right +
        ", parent=" + parent +
        ", height=" + height +
        ", key=" + key +
        ", value=" + value +
        '}';
  }
}
```

Output:

```
AVLNode{left=null, right=null, parent=null, height=1, key=test1, value=asdfasdf}
AVLNode{left=null, right=null, parent=null, height=1, key=test2, value=bds}
AVLNode{left=null, right=null, parent=null, height=1, key=test3, value=asd}
AVLNode{left=null, right=null, parent=null, height=1, key=test8, value=asdfas}
```

P.S. Actually, I checked @MadProgrammer suggestion. It works this way as well

...

```
Comparator myComp2 = new Comparator<AVLNode>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(AVLNode n1, AVLNode n2) {
        return n1.getKey().compareTo(n2.getKey());
      }
    };
```

...

```
class AVLNode<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {
```

...

Compiler just needs to know that your `key` implements `Comparable`

Answer (score 5):

`AVLNode` is generic, parameterized with `K` and `V`. In your `Comparator<AVLNode>`, `AVLNode` is raw. That is, `K` and `V` are unknown. This means the compiler actually does not know if `K` is `Comparable`.

Try making it `Comparator<AVLNode<String, ?>>`.

Unrelated, but also use `new AVLNode<>(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use raw types, better to write:

```
Comparator<AVLNode<Type1, Type2> comparator ...
```

For example:

```
Comparator<AVLNode<String, Cuboid>> myComp2 = new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(AVLNode<String, Cuboid> n1, AVLNode<String, Cuboid> n2) {
        return n1.getKey().compareTo(n2.getKey());
    }
};
```

By the way, you can use the [`Comparator.comparing(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) instead of anonymous class, for example:

```
Comparator<AVLNode<String, Cuboid>> comparator = Comparator.comparing(AVLNode::getKey);
```

Answer (score 2):

`K` in `AVLNode` doesn't not include a conformance to `Comparable` (from where `compareTo` might come from)

You could add an additional constraint to `K` so that all keys must conform to `Comparable`, something like...

```
public class AVLNode<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {
    //...
}
```

This places the limitation onto `AVLNode` itself, so beware (that all keys must implement `Comparable`)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring raw `AVLNode` objects in your comparator. That is why only methods of class `Object` are available for `AVLNode.getKey()`.

Change your Comparator declaration to this

```
Comparator<AVLNode<String, Cuboid>> myComp2 = new Comparator<AVLNode<String, Cuboid>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(AVLNode<String, Cuboid> o1, AVLNode<String, Cuboid> o2) {
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

Comment: `Cuboid` is actually irrelevant in this comparator.